# threads in java android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am using some threads in java android, I have a class which implements the runnable interface, for this i need to have a run method and this run method is called when a thread starts for example thread.start(), my problem is that i dont know how to run 2 different run methods and 2 threads. skeleton of code is below. please help on this or some explanation.Thanks a lot.

```
public class myTutorialsDetailsRequest implements Runnable {

    //on click of button 1 start the below thread 
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

      public void run() {
       //do get data 1
      }
    //onlick of button 2 start the below thread 
         Thread thread2 = new Thread(this);
    thread2.start();

      public void run() {
       //do get data 2
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own subclass of Thread for each thread you need. You may either define one class in one file or the common way (but maybe a bit harder to read for Java beginners) is to do so inline by using an anonymous class:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        //...
    }
}.start();
```

This defines a new subclass of Thread without giving it a name. 
Do the same for the second thread.

However, consider carefully whether you really need to spawn a new thread for whatever it is you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is that i dont know how to run 2 different run methods and 2 threads

For two different run methods, you need two different Runnable classes (or some parameterization).

```
 new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();

 new Thread(new MyOtherRunnable()).start();
```